# finding partial text from a string

Tags: sed, awk, grep

My text file has a few lines like this...

```
some data here Waiting on job_bba6b2a1589b4535a804e7877dc1fe11 ... (409s) Current status: DONE 
some data there Waiting on job_xyz ... (240s) Current status: DONE
```

I need to find the job id. In the example mentioned above...

```
bba6b2a1589b4535a804e7877dc1fe11
xyz
```

I can use grep, but how to select only the ID?

cat file.log | grep 'Waiting on job_'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is what you need?

```
kent$  echo "some data here Waiting on job_bba6b2a1589b4535a804e7877dc1fe11 ... (409s)"|grep -oP "(?<=Waiting on job_)[^ ]*" 
bba6b2a1589b4535a804e7877dc1fe11
```

Comment: +1 - for versions of `grep` that support PCRE such as GNU and OS X.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*Waiting on job_\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

For each line containing `Waiting on job_` followed by 0 or more non-space characters, this will substitute the whole line (because starting and ending `.*` are going to greedily take as many characters as possible) using back-reference `\1` to recall everything that was matched between `\(` and `\)`, i.e. the non space characters `[^ ]*` you are looking for.

So:

```
cat file.log | grep 'Waiting on job_' | sed 's/.*Waiting on job_\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

or simpler:

```
grep 'Waiting on job_' file.log | sed 's/.*Waiting on job_\([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if m/(?<=Waiting on job_)([^ ]*)/' inputfile
```